# FIWARE Wirecloud Mashup: NGSI Source + Public/Testing ContextBroker (Probable NGSI Proxy Issue)

Tags: proxy, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I am trying to build a simple Wirecloud Application Mashup, with the "NGSI source" and "Map Viewer" components, like the one described [here](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Application_Mashup_-_Wirecloud_-_User_and_Programmer_Guide) but using the testing service available at 130.206.80.40.
Since I am a newcomer to the FIWARE platform, I started by following [these](https://www.fiware.org/devguides/connection-to-the-internet-of-things/how-to-read-measures-captured-from-iot-devices/) simple instructions and managed to successfully create a virtual (python) device, publish and read observations to/from it. Then, I played with the FIWARE Lab for a while and also managed to successfully use the "NGSI browser" and "Spy Wiring" widgets to read my device's data. Finally, when I tried to use the "NGSI source" operator to "automatise" the readings, nothing happened. Components configurations below:

**NGSI Browser**

```
NGSI server URL: http://130.206.80.40:1026/
Use the FIWARE credentials of the user: Yes
NGSI entity types: [LEFT_BLANK]
Id pattern: test123
Extra Attributes: temp
```

**NGSI Source**

```
NGSI server URL: http://130.206.80.40:1026/
NGSI proxy URL: https://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org (also tried other addresses, without success)
Use the FIWARE credentials of the user: Yes
Use the FIWARE credentials of the workspace owner: No (also tried with "Yes")
NGSI entity types: [LEFT_BLANK]
Id pattern: test123
Monitored NGSI Attributes: temp
```

Please note that the "NGSI Source" operator worked perfectly with its default configuration.

Moreover I've also read on jira.fiware.org that the ContextBroker must support HTTPS; does that mean that the public testing server doesn't support it and that I can't use it for my final purpose? Or there is a way to use it without the NGSI proxy (another operator perhaps)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPs support has been added to that instance.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for that Carlos.However, the "NGSI Browser" stopped to work with Figway (which was previously working). I am able to send observations (using the SendObservation.py script with fiware_service=openiot) to IDAS on 130.206.80.40:5371 and read them from the Context Broker on 130.206.80.40:1026 (using GetEntityAttribute.py), but I can't manage to get them on the Mashup. Any extra help would be appreciated. Thanks.